# PHP checking if all inputs were set doesn't function?

Tags: php, scope

So I started using MVC.  I don't use a framework.  It's just self-practice.

So this is my register part:

```
    protected function _instance()
    {
        if ($_POST != null)
        {
            /**
            * Validating if forms are not empty
            **/

            if (self::validateForms())
            {
                echo 1;
            }
            else
            {
                new Error("One of the forums was empty..");
            }
        }
    }

    private static function validateForms()
    {
        $inputs = array (
            'username', 'password', 'repassword',
            'email', 'password_f', 'repassword_f',
            'display'
        );

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($inputs as $key)
        {
            if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key]))
            {
                $i++;
                if ((int) $i == count($inputs))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it only must check if inputs were set, if not, throw error.
But it seems like it doesn't work as it always runs that error.

`$i` must grow everytime a input was full, but I don't think it does.

When I do echo `$i`, it only echoing "1".

Why is it only looping through it once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are returning within your loop after the first test.

```
    foreach ($inputs as $key)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key]))
        {
            $i++;
            if ((int) $i == count($inputs))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

should be

```
    foreach ($inputs as $key)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key]))
        {
            $i++;
        } 
    }
    if ((int) $i == count($inputs))
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

or more concisely

```
    foreach ($inputs as $key)
    {
        if (!isset($_POST[$key]) || empty($_POST[$key]))
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: How could I miss that! Must be tired. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the checking of `$i` out of the loop so that it checks how many were actually set once all the inputs have been cycled through.  Otherwise, it is checking on the first time, seeing that it is not equal and returning false.

```
foreach ($inputs as $key)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key]))
    {
        $i++;
    }
}
if ((int) $i == count($inputs))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```